# Getting contents of HTML page to text file but without the code. Just plain text

Tags: c++, web, curl

Good day to you,

I've been trying to save web page to text file with cURL. But this is giving me trouble because cURL is saving the whole web page code instead of just the original output text. Basically I'm trying to generate junk code from https://junkcode.gehaxelt.in/ and save it in a text file. If you right click on the page source for this website and scroll through you will see dereference pointers, especially at the bottle in the 'this' pointer section, and this isn't what I want. I don't want the dereference pointers. I just want the plain text of the website.

If you right click the page and save it as a text file it does exactly what I want, but if I call it from cURL it saves the whole php code. How can I fix this?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a job for curl, because curl is not a HTML parser. use libxml2: http://xmlsoft.org/ , something like

```
std::string htmlToText(std::string html){
    htmlDocPtr doc = htmlReadMemory(html.data(), html.length(), "noname.html", "UTF-8", htmlParserOption::HTML_PARSE_RECOVER | htmlParserOption::HTML_PARSE_NODEFDTD | htmlParserOption::HTML_PARSE_NOERROR | htmlParserOption::HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | htmlParserOption::HTML_PARSE_NOBLANKS  | htmlParserOption::HTML_PARSE_NONET);
    if (doc == NULL) {
        throw std::runtime_error("unable to parse as html (todo libxml2 error message extraction)");
    }
    std::string ret=xmlNodeGetContent(doc);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: "*use libxml2*" - or any number of other HTML/XHTML parsers that are available.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sure, but libxml2 is very ubiquitous, it's available in the default repos of all major linux distributions, it's the library of which all of PHP's DOMDocument/DOMXPath is based, it ships with Perl, it ships with OpenOffice & LibreOffice, it ships with VLC Media Player,  if you have a Windows-system around and run `cd \; dir *libxml*.dll /s /b` you're likely to get several hits (i do), if you have a Linux system and run `find / -iname "*libxml*" 2>/dev/null` you're also likely to get hits; libxml2 is a *very popular library* for parsing XML/HTML